# Good framework for the game of Go (weiqi, baduk)?

Tags: linux, macos, language-agnostic, open-source, baduk

I enjoy the game of [Go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28game%29) (also known as weiqi in China or baduk in Korea).  I want to create a program (an evaluation function) to play it.

I would prefer if the framework handled two important tasks:

- Handle rules for the game, including captures, ko rules, and final scoring.
- Handle communication between a server like KGS and my program.

Also, my home machines run Linux or Mac OS X; I cannot use any only-Windows platforms.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[GNU Go](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnugo/) is a great open source Go program. Its evaluation function is [well-documented](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnugo/gnugo_toc.html) and it provides an easy way to output the explanation for every move the program made. You can either replace the evaluation function from scratch with your own, or tinker with the existing one.

[Open Go](http://www.inventivity.com/OpenGo/doc/ReleaseNotes.html) is an open source tool with code for communicating using the Go Modem Protocol. I believe that's what you need for the second part of your question.

Comment: Gnu Go is excellent for the first half -- it has all the rules and final scoring -- but it doesn't handle communication with servers by itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but for people out there interested in an Android implementation of Go (Baduk/Weiqi) take a look at my project on https://github.com/amgreg/AndroidGo

It's a simple validator with a user-interface attached.  Drawbacks are:  No AI; no scoring; no server connection.